# Dynamic, nested, links on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i've been trying to redirect links, to a dynamic route, link. I used React Router DOM to do this, and it works, but now i want to do with vanilla JS, but i don't know how

I tryed solutions in other forums and more solutions, but don't works
This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="goto123()">Go to 123</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my vanilla JS script

```
function goto123(){
    let current = window.location.href
    let setNewCurrent = '/123'
    window.location.replace(`${current}` + setNewCurrent)
}
```

The URL writes correctly, but the document gives me this error: Cannot GET /index.html/123
Any solution will be received, Thanks

Comment: The server doesn't have a route defined for "/index.html/123". Maybe you should use History API instead. ```history.pushState({}, '', newUrl);```

Comment: The history.pushState works correctly, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
function goto123(){
    let current = window.location.href
    let setNewCurrent = '#/123'
    window.location.replace(`${current}` + setNewCurrent)
}
```

But Linking to an element on the same page